# How to check if Selection for Combobox is changed from UI or Business Logic

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I have a combobox bound to an itemsource of collection, I am changing the selection from both code-behind and the user can change the selection from UI.
Is there anyway to check where the selection is changed from i.e UI or my logic.

I tried to use OriginalSource from the EventArgs in Selection changed event but to no avail? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Just set some flag (boolean field of your class, for example) when you're changing selection from your code.

Thus, if flag is not set when selection changed event occurs - it was user who caused selection changing. If flag was set - then selection changed was invoked by your business logic.

Of course, don't forget to clear that flag back in selection changed event handler.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **nullable boolean flag** as `bool? IsChangedByUser = null;`. At first set it to null so that selection has not changed from anywhere.

Now if user changes it, make it `true`. If you change it from code, make it `false`.